# Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell (Minimum) Fatal Error during installation

Tags: visual-studio, installation

Got an error while installing `Visual Studio 2015 Community` i have search for any site and common issues and workaround but it has no necessary answers.

Here is part of my log file.

```
[0DE8:2228][2016-06-06T00:50:17]i000: MUX:  Apply Complete: Disk Space Used in bytes for Installation:  MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 98938880  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 9031680
[0DE8:2228][2016-06-06T00:50:17]i000: MUX:  Free Disk Space after install:  SystemDrive C:\ 121211363328 bytes  AppDrive C:\ 121211363328 bytes
[0DE8:2228][2016-06-06T00:50:17]i000: MUX:  Go to Finished page.
[0DE8:2228][2016-06-06T00:50:17]i000: MUX:  Watson Bucketting Parameters
[0DE8:2228][2016-06-06T00:50:17]i000: MUX:  P1 - vs_community
[0DE8:2228][2016-06-06T00:50:17]i000: MUX:  P2 - 14.0.23107.10
[0DE8:2228][2016-06-06T00:50:17]i000: MUX:  P3 - 14.0.23107
[0DE8:2228][2016-06-06T00:50:17]i000: MUX:  P4 - Install
[0DE8:2228][2016-06-06T00:50:17]i000: MUX:  P5 - Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell (Minimum)
[0DE8:2228][2016-06-06T00:50:17]i000: MUX:  P6 - Install
[0DE8:2228][2016-06-06T00:50:17]i000: MUX:  P7 - 0x80070643
[0DE8:2228][2016-06-06T00:50:17]i000: MUX:  P8 - An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.Measurement,version="14.0.0.0",publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a",processorArchitecture="MSIL",fileVersion="14.0.23107.0",culture="neutral"'. Please refer to Help and Support for more information. 
[0DE8:2228][2016-06-06T00:50:17]i000: MUX:  P9 - 0x80070020,Commit,MSIL,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.Measurement
[0DE8:2228][2016-06-06T00:50:17]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80070643, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just solved my problem by deleting all files inside `%temp%` folder and restarted the computer.